# Error al agregar origen de datos en Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Tengo un proyecto WPF en Visual Studio con .NET Framework 4.7.2 y he creado una conexión a una base de datos SQL Server correctamente, pero al agregar un nuevo origen de datos recibo el siguiente error:

> Error de la herramienta personalizada: No se pudo generar código. No se pudo generar código. No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.OracleClient.dll' ni una de sus dependencias. Los ensamblados de referencia no deben cargarse para la ejecución. Se pueden cargar únicamente en el contexto de cargador solo para la reflexión. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131058) No se puede cargar un ensamblado de referencia para la ejecución. No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.OracleClient.dll' ni una de sus dependencias. Los ensamblados de referencia no deben cargarse para la ejecución. Se pueden cargar únicamente en el contexto de cargador solo para la reflexión. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131058) No se puede cargar un ensamblado de referencia para la ejecución.

Después de recibir este error el dataset se crea correctamente pero el origen de datos no aparece en el panel correspondiente.

Ya reinstalé Visual Studio, he creado un nuevo proyecto y el error sigue apareciendo.

Otro detalle importante es que si creo el origen de datos sin seleccionar ninguna tabla si funciona, pero cuando lo actualizo para agregar las tablas vuelve a presentar el mismo error y desaparece del panel de "orígenes de datos".

Comment: Puede ser que el dll de oracle no sea compatible con el .net 4.7.2 revisar si el dll de oracle es para version 11 o 10, otro cosa seria que utilizaras vs 2017